# Ligatures in mathrm mode

Tags: math-mode, equations, ligatures, mathrm

In an equation, I want to print a subscript without ligatures. LaTeX automatically connects the characters when in math mode with `\mathrm`. I tried using the [selnolig](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/selnolig) package providing the command `\nolig{eff}{ef|f}` without success. The result I get:

[image]

As seen, the `ff`'s in eff are connected, which is not desired. The `\nolig{eff}{ef|f}` command does work in normal text, just not in math mode with `\mathrm`. Does anyone have a solution for locally disabling ligatures or an alternative to `\mathrm`?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The `selnolig` package works only under LuaLaTeX. It does *not* work under either pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX. However, the following test document (which doesn't even load `selnolig`!) -- `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{fontspec} \begin{document} $\mathrm{eff}$ $\sqrt{\varepsilon_{\mathrm{eff}}}$ \end{document}` -- does *not* produce `ff`-ligatures in the "eff" substrings when compiled under LuaLaTeX. Again, no need to load `selnolig` and run `\nolig{eff}{ef|f}`. Please clarify what exactly you've tried. In particular, do state how you compile your document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way to locally split up a ligature is to use an italic correction by adding `\/` or `{}` between the f & f:

```
\lambda_g = \frac{c}{f\sqrt{\varepsilon_{\mathrm{ef\/f}}}}
```

or

```
\lambda_g = \frac{c}{f\sqrt{\varepsilon_{\mathrm{ef{}f}}}}
```

Comment: I ended up using the first solution including `\/`. Thanks a lot!